# No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I want to make a gridview that when I select a row, its values will be populated to another gridview and text boxes, but I am encountering the error above. When I click the row in the GridView2, nothing is happening and an error in the sqladapter occurs. Please help me to fix this code..

Here is my code:
c#

```
protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT MRPNo, MRPType, MRPDate FROM MRP WHERE MRPNo = @mrpno",con);
    com.Parameters.Add("@mrpno", GridView2.SelectedRow);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
    txtMRPNo.Text = row["MRPNo"].ToString();
    txtMRPDate.Text = row["MRPType"].ToString();
    txtMRPDate.Text = row["MRPDate"].ToString();
    GridView3.DataBind();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton selectButton = new LinkButton()
    {
        CommandName = "Select",
        Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text,
    };
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(selectButton);
}

protected void GridView2_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView2, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use GridView2.SelectedRow as an input to Parameters.Add(). Please refer to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow(v=vs.110).aspx) and you will see why.